# How to store users score in Firebase with android studio and how to access the child node in firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I have been trying to make an app that would let users take an assessment and then reveal their score. The registration of users is already working however i am trying to add score node in that parent node. I cant access the child node and i cant update the users score. please help me.[image: The User is the parent node and its child is Rona.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference ref = rootRef.child("Users").child("Rona");
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("score", 0);
ref.updateChildren(map);
```

The result will be the addition of the `score` property in your database with the value of `0`.

**Edit:** According to your comment:

> but i wanted to access other users to. not just Rona

To solve this, you need to use a query that looks like this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query query = rootRef.child("Users").orderByChild("username");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) ds.getValue();
            map.put("score", 0);
            ds.getRef().updateChildren(map);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());
    }
};
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Using the above code, you'll be able to update the `score` property not only to `Rona` but to all the other users.

Comment: thanks for this. but i wanted to access other users to. not just Rona i dont want to specify on who to put the score with.

Comment: like if other users will have to register, i will have to get the username but i dont know how to do that.

Comment: Please update your question to show the [minimal code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @RonaCeciliaAbayata Please see my updated answer. Does it work now?

Comment: Oh, my bad. Please see my updated answer. Is it ok now?

Comment: Hi Rona! Have you tried my updated solution, does it work?

Comment: Hi @AlexMamo i tried to use the code. there was an error in Log and the Tag

Comment: @AlexMamo the Log was resolved However the TAG is not.

Comment: @RonaCeciliaAbayata In this case, change `Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());` to `Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage());`. Does it work now?

Comment: @AlexMamo its now working but im trying to set the score part to the total score but its not changing. I already change 0 to total

Comment: Good to hear that it worked! Trying to set the score part to the total score sounds as another challenge. So you should make your own attempt with the information from my answer and ask another question if something else comes up.

Comment: @AlexMamo it is now working. Thank You so much. You really helped me. this is my step to graduation. please help me again if ever i need help

Comment: @AlexMamo THANK YOU SO MUCH!! :)))

Comment: @AlexMamo can you help me with something again? I wanted to terminate the music playing everytime i hit the back button. whether it would be the button i created or the back button of the phone itself. what should i do?

Comment: In order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question, so me and other users can help you.

Comment: Okay ill post a question now.

Comment: So you don't think that my answer can help other users in the future?

Comment: Yes. I think it will help them cause it definitely helped me

Comment: @AlexMamo how can i do it without changing all the children under the Users?

Comment: Please post another fresh question, so me and other users can help you.